Nested Multi<Uni> in Quarkus Kafka and Mongo Reactive Combo
I am trying to convert an experimenting Spring Cloud Streams Kafka project to Quarkus Kafka with ReactiveMongoRepositories.
Signature of Kafka consumer metod and related fields:
@Channel
Multi<Message<Employee> employees;
@Inject
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

public Multi<Message<Employee> consume(){}

Repository finder method signature is:
Uni<Employee> findEmployeeInfo(String id);

What I am trying to do, is to get message from employee Multi, extract id from Message, then enrich employee object in message payload by using a setter metohd on Employee class, after a repository call .
Here are my issues and questions:
Below returns Multi<Uni>. How can I avoid nested situation and get Multi like below? Actual return is Multi<Uni>
Multi<Employee> empMulti= employees
                                  .map(msg->msg.getPayload().getEmployeeId())
                                  .map(id->employeeRepository.findEmployeeInfo(id));

One thing I also tried is below but compiler complains about type inference(incompatible types: inference variable O has incompatible bounds). Looks like last map returns Message. How to fix this since I think this is more reactive style?
    return employees.map(msg -> employeeRepository
                               .findEmployeeInfo(msg.getPayload().getEmployeeId()))
                               .map(employee-> { 
                                           msg.getPayload().setEmployeeInfo(employee);
                                           return msg;})

My problem is indeed same or very similar to my other question below with some differences between Reactor and SmallRye frameworks:

The second map should be an onItem().transformToUniAndMerge() (or onItem().transformToUniAndConcatenate() if you want to preserve the order).
At the moment, you second map returns a Uni<Employee>.
